# gem to commit files into svn from ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, svn

Hey I am working on ruby on rails application where user can create set of instructions in the form of text. We have a requirement to save this text (dynamic) into svn. Could someone suggest which is the best gem to achieve below:

1. I have to push text into git as a .txt file.
2. I need to checkout latest text from svn to the UI.
3. If any conflicts, need to handle error messages.
4. We need to show all the files available in svn repo.

Help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a gem that does that, but this seems like a good start

http://www.agileweboperations.com/super-simple-ruby-subversion-command-line-wrapper